# How to convert Timestamp - Datetime to dd-MM-yyy without time

Tags: powershell

I'm running a powershell script and exporting the output for a rapport.

Tried different format possibilities to change `dd-MM-YYYY HH-MM-SS` to just showing `dd-MM-YYYY` but can't figure it out

```
@{Name="Date"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)}}
```

I'm getting `30-10-2017 10:07:10` and only want to get the output `30-10-2017`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert them to the required format using the below statement.

```
@{Name="Date"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')}}
```

Check this documentation for more reference!

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the value as a `DateTime`, e.g.

```
$date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp)
```

You can use one of the `ToString` overloads provided by the object type, e.g.

```
$formattedDate = $date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

You can get further information about formatting options on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) link.